# Please help using MySQL to select into where the data to write requires one select statement and the records to be created require another

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

I have a scenario where I want to select a set of records in a table, then based on a second select write new records into the table from the first select.

The table I wish to select from then write to is:

```
bullets
-------
id
product_code
catalogue_category_id
bullet_text
sort_sequence
```

Note id is the key and is an auto incrementing integer

I select the records as follows:

```sql
SELECT product_code, catalogue_category_id, bullet_text, sort_sequence 
  FROM bullets 
 WHERE product_code = '10001'
```

For this product this gives 4 rows, the number of bullets may vary from one product to another.  The result is:

```
10001, , Bullet point for testing - 10001,  
10001, , 2nd bullet    point,  
10001, , 3rd bullet point,  
10001, , 4th bullet,
```

In this case the catalogue_category_id and sort_sequence are empty, this will not always be the case.

I then want to select a number of product codes and write, in this case, 4 records one for each bullet point.

The second select statement to get the list of product codes is

```sql
SELECT product_code 
  FROM master 
 WHERE product_group = '1' 
   AND product_code != '10001'
```

This gives 17 product codes back but it could be less or more depending on the product_group being selected.

The new records will comprise:

```
id - this will be auto incremented
product_code - this will be the new product code from the second select statement
catalogue_category_id - this will be the selected data from the first select statement
bullet_text - this will be the selected data from the first select statement
sort_sequence - this will be the selected data from the first select statement
```

So in this example I would write a total of 68 new records into bullets, 4 each for each of the 17 product codes.

I think I need a stored procedure to do this but have searched and can't wrap my head around the results I have looked at.  Any help much appreciated.

The 68 records will be written to the bullets table as new records.  The selected records may have all or any combination of the four fields populated:

```
product_code, catalogue_category_id, bullet_text, sort_sequence
```

Essentially I am looking to duplicate the selected records with the exception of the id and the product code.  For example say I have 3 product codes,

```
10002, 10003 & 10004
```

returned using my second select statement then I would get 12 new records, 3 sets of 4 that are almost identical to the initial 4 from my first SELECT statement, the ID would autoincrement and the product code would beL

```
10002 for the first 4 new records
10003 for the next 4 new records
10004 for the last 4
```

I will write whatever is selected for each field.  Using your example where 2 of the 4 records selected have data in the catalogue_category_id field then 34 of the 68 new records would have data in the catalogue_category_id field.

Comment: where will you want to write `68 new records`? or by that you mean you want to retrieve 68 records. what if in the first `select` statement gives for records and two of them has already `catalogue_category_id`? what will be the output then?

Comment: Hi JW
Thanks I have answered your question above, any help appreciated.  Mike

Answer (score 0):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17642588/1920232) all you need is `CROSS JOIN`

```sql
INSERT INTO bullets (product_code, catalogue_category_id, bullet_text, sort_sequence) 
SELECT m.product_code, b.catalogue_category_id, b.bullet_text, b.sort_sequence
  FROM bullets b CROSS JOIN master m
 WHERE b.product_code = 10001
   AND m.product_group = 3
   AND m.product_code <> 10001;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae163/1)** demo